# C++ How to replace #defines with consts

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

Recently I've been taking a hard look at my programming style and how to improve it.  Let me begin by saying that in my current role, I'm the sole programmer.  As a result, I can make things as hacky as I want, but I'm really striving to become a better, more sound programmer.

Also, my background was mainly C based, with essentially using C++ as a super-set of C when necessary.  As a result, I have stumbled across the following conundrum.

I have always defined error codes with something like #define ERROR_FUNCTION_BLEW_UP -2 .  In honesty, I can see the benefits of doing so since I don't have to allocate the memory to store -2.  However, in C++ I can see the benefit of using a const variable since there's less chances of collisions between two competing macros.

As a result, I was wondering what the cleanest way is to implement error codes in C++.  Namely, I'd like to have the client be able to check the return value of certain functions by doing something analogous to "if (return_value == ERROR_FUNCTION_BLEW_UP)".  I've tried adding a const variable in each class, but then the code doesn't look right.  That is, the client now checks something along the lines of "if (return_value == MyClass.kErrorFunctionBlewUp_)".  Is there a cleaner way of accomplishing this, rather than having the constant be a public member of the class?

Also, to add onto my question, myClass is a base class, and now I want to add more error codes in MyDerivedClass.  What's the best way of going about this and avoiding macros?

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `enum`s:

```
enum Errors
{
    NO_ERROR = 0,
    FUNCTION_BLEW_UP,
    WTF_THIS_SHOULDNT_HAPPEN,
};
```

Also, consider using exceptions (look into `std::exception`) if they're more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.  I have done some preliminary research, but I still have some questions: 1. Where is the "best" place to define the enum?  That is, do I place it at the top of the file before the class to ensure that the client receives it by including my file?  2. Do I now have to change my functions that return the error codes to return the enum type? 3. How do I handle my case of the derived classes?  That is, the derived class should take in all of the attributes of the base class's error, but add a few of their own.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are pros and cons to using enums. If you don't abuse casting, you can get some type safety preventing using the wrong name for the wrong parameter, etc; if you turn on the relevant compiler warnings, it will also let you know if you haven't checked for a particular value in a switch statement. cons: you wind up doing casting frequently when you are using them for things like flags, etc.

A popular way to use them is to do something like this: `enum COFFEE_ROAST_TYPE { COFFEE_ROAST_TYPE_DARK, COFFEE_ROAST_TYPE_GO_HOME, MAX_COFFEE_ROAST_TYPES };`

Comment: @kfsone - if you're using an enum as a flag, overload the appropriate bitwise operators. You don't have to write casts outside the operators.

Comment: @kfsone: If you're using them as flags, the type storing the combination of flags should be an `int` or `unsigned int` type.  For example: `int x = enumFlag1 | enumFlag2;`

Comment: No, when using them as flags do what Pete says if you want type safety.

Comment: Honestly, both of those solutions are kinda unfortunate, although imho the overloading path is just as unfortunate as the casting. Other cases include where you might want to do: `for (COFFEE_ROAST_TYPE i = 0; i < MAX_COFFEE_ROAST_TYPES; ++i)` -- this should probably be something the language lets you easily implement without overloads or casts. It doesn't.

Still, I think using enums is a good route to take, having the added "pro" that many debuggers and IDEs will translate values for you better than they do for static constants and #defines.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to just replace your macros, replace them with a constant. A constant has internal linkage (i.e. restricted to the translation unit ("file")) so the compiler can easily replace their use with just the constant inline and without using a single byte more or less than for a macro. Note that it is customary to keep ALL_UPPERCASE to macros, because macros don't follow normal code conventions, so you'd have to change that, too.

Then, in C++, you don't generally use returncodes that the caller has to check but exceptions which propagate automatically. If you want to keep the errorcodes, you can use an enumeration or constants and put them into a namespace. Note that enumerations leak into the surrounding namespace or class, which makes it preferable to wrap them up one level:

```
namespace errorcode
{
    enum type
    {
        printer_on_fire,
        volume_not_formatted,
        bluescreen
    };
}
```

Exceptions do sometimes contain error codes that further specify what failed though. Here's one way to specify them:

```
struct error:
    std::runtime_error
{
    ...

    enum code
    {
        printer_on_fire,
        volume_not_formatted,
        bluescreen
    };

    code fault;
};
```

Note that you don't have to nest the code, you can also build the exception type with the existing `errorcode::type` above. Some nesting is useful though, because enumerations otherwise pollute the surrounding namespace.

That said, you ask "do I place it at the top of the file before the class", but here you have a misconception. Firstly, not every file contains a class. Then, not every file that contains a class contains exactly one of them. For example, if the collection of errorcodes is used by a whole class hierarchy it makes sense to define it in a separate file to make clear that it doesn't belong to just one of them and that it can be used in related non-class functions, too. In that file, you would also stick e.g. a function to convert it to a string for debugging and maybe the exception type carrying one of them.